# Migrate node with paragraph

Tags: 8, migrations, paragraphs

I'm trying to figure out how migrating content from a Drupal 7 site to a Drupal 8 site works. I managed to understand how to create a custom module to migrate nodes with regular fields to my new D8 site.

But I also have one content type where I use paragraphs. And I can't seem to find a well documented example on how to do this. I found some examples but they all seem to use different methods. [This](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2990527) one seems like the most up to date. But how to make the code from [#9](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2990527#comment-12843119) work?

```
field_paragraphs:
plugin: sub_process
source: field_source_paragraphs
process:
  target_id:
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration:
        - paragraph_box
        - paragraph_grid
        - paragraph_text_embedded
      source: value
    -
      plugin: extract
      index:
        - 0
  target_revision_id:
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration:
        - paragraph_box
        - paragraph_grid
        - paragraph_text_embedded
      source: value
    -
      plugin: extract
      index:
        - 0
```

So the `field_paragraphs` and `field_source_paragraphs` I understand. But what are these `paragraph_` items under migration? Is this where I set the paragraph bundles? And if not where do I set the paragraph bundles and there fields? So where do I begin? What are the right steps to take?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this? https://softescu.com/blog/knowledge-centre/how-migrate-paragraphs-paragraphs-drupal-7-drupal-8 I found it very helpful for migrating my own nodes with paragraphs 7 to 8.

Comment: That link has changed: https://softescu.com/blog/how-migrate-paragraphs-drupal-7-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a plugin within your custom module in order to migrate paragraph fields properly. I just finished this process on a large site. I'm paring down the module to make it a bit easier to understand and making it available in a public repository, along with an explanatory video:

https://www.arsnova.cc/drupal-7-drupal-8-paragraph-migration